# How to write String format of binary value to registry using Delphi and writebinary command?

Tags: string, delphi, binary, registry

Fore some good reason i need to write a string format of a binary value to a binary registry key, in other words I have a registry value like this :

```
 Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Sonal]
 "Password"=hex:00,d6
```

I tried to write it to registry using following code :

```
procedure Tesct.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
RegInfoExists : TRegistry;
EdStr : AnsiString;
begin

try
   RegInfoExists := TRegistry.Create(KEY_WRITE OR KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
   RegInfoExists.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
   if RegInfoExists.OpenKey('SOFTWARE\Sonal',true) then
     EdStr := #$00#$d6;
     RegInfoExists.WriteBinaryData('Password', EdStr,
       Length(EdStr) * SizeOf(byte));

 except

 end;
 RegInfoExists.CloseKey;
 RegInfoExists.Free;
end;
```

And I got this :

```
 Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Sonal]
 "Password"=hex:dc,d7
```

How i can do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are writing the value of the `string` variable which is the address of the string. That's because at an implementation level, strings are simply pointers.

Instead you need to de-reference the pointer. Two commonly used ways to do that:

```
RegInfoExists.WriteBinaryData('Password', EdStr[1], 
  Length(EdStr)*SizeOf(AnsiChar));
```

or

```
RegInfoExists.WriteBinaryData('Password', Pointer(EdStr)^, 
  Length(EdStr)*SizeOf(AnsiChar));
```

If you really are just trying to write those two bytes then it is easier like this:

```
const
  Password: array [0..1] of byte = ($00, $d6);
....
RegInfoExists.WriteBinaryData('Password', Password, Length(Password));
```

---

I would also comment that you should be very strict and precise in the way you look after resources. That means using `try/finally` correctly. Like this:

```
SomeInstance := TSomeClass.Create;
try
  .... do stuff with SomeInstance
finally
  SomeInstance.Free;
end;
```

And you also seem to have omitted the `begin`/`end` that you need for the code that follows the `if` statement.

Comment: in addition a `begin ... end` might be usefull.

Comment: Thank you for your time,  Yes I forget to put begin .... end. No it is not just 2 byte. Yes  I should be more careful about resources. tank you very much david